# Highlighting showcmd in vim

Tags: vim, colors

`vim` has the option to set `showcmd`. It causes part of the entered command to be shown at the bottom line, on the right. If I am not wrong, it shows up to 10 last typed characters.

What I wish to know is whether there's a way to control the colour of these displayed characters. Normally it is displayed in `vim`'s default colour (`Normal`), so if I modify `Normal` it colours the `showcmd` text in that colour as well - but with that, it colours my entire text, my command line, etc.

Do you know of a way to highlight the `showcmd` characters **only**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to influence the coloring of `'showcmd'`. You'd have to modify Vim's source code to achieve something like this. You can ask on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) for help, and post your patch for comments and eventual inclusion there.

Making it more obvious that Vim is still waiting for keys to complete the command (by using different, stronger colors) could be perceived as beneficial, so there are good chances for inclusion of such a patch.